# How to work with variable-sized image in CNNs using Keras?

Tags: python-2.7, keras, conv-neural-network, dimension

I am currently working on CNN on a image for feature extraction using keras. All the images as 276 rows, x columns and 3 color dimensions (RGB). 
The number of columns is equal to the length of the output feature vector it should generate.

Input data representation - edit:

**The input data given to the image consist of columnwise slices of the image. which means the actual input to the image is (276,3)  and number of of columns is equal to the feature length it should generate.**

My initial model is as such:

```
    print "Model Definition"
    model = Sequential()

    model.add(Convolution2D(64,row,1,input_shape=(row,None,3)))
    print model.output_shape
    model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(1,64)))
    print model.output_shape
    model.add(Dense(1,activation='relu'))
```

My prints in between prints the `output.shape`,and I seem to be bit confused on the output.

```
Model Definition
(None, 1, None, 64)
(None, 1, None, 64)
```

How come is the 3D data become 4d? And keeps being that after the maxpoolling2d layer?.

My dense layer/fully-connected layer is giving me some problems with the dimensions here:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "keras_convolutional_feature_extraction.py", line 466, in <module>
    model(0,train_input_data,output_data_train,test_input_data,output_data_test)
  File "keras_convolutional_feature_extraction.py", line 440, in model
    model.add(Dense(1,activation='relu'))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/models.py", line 324, in add
    output_tensor = layer(self.outputs[0])
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 474, in __call__
    self.assert_input_compatibility(x)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/topology.py", line 415, in assert_input_compatibility
    str(K.ndim(x)))
Exception: Input 0 is incompatible with layer dense_1: expected ndim=2, found ndim=4
```

So why am i not able to get the data down to a 1 single value from a 3D image. ?

Comment: See my edit. Also I changed your question title to better reflect the issue. If you disagree with it, feel free to change it back.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are operating on a `276 x None x 3` image using 64 convolutional filters, each of size `276 x 1` (assuming `rows = 276`). One convolutional filter will output a matrix of size `1 x None`. Read [this](http://cs231n.github.io/convolutional-networks/#conv) in detail if you do not know how convolutional filters work. So for 64 filters, (in Theano backend) you will get a matrix of size `64 x 1 x None`. In Tensorflow backend, I think it will be `1 x None x 64`. Now, first dimension for Keras-Theano is always samples. So, your final output shape will be `None x 64 x 1 x None`. For Tensorflow, it will be `None x 1 x None x 64`. Read [this](https://keras.io/backend/) for more information on different backends in Keras.

To remove the dense layer error, I think you will need to flatten the output by introducing the following line before adding `Dense` layer.

```
model.add(Flatten())
```

However, I do not really understand the use of dense layer here. As you must be aware, the dense layer only accepts a fixed input size and provides a fixed size output. So your `None` dimension will be basically restricted to a single value if you want your network to run without throwing errors. If you want to have an output of the shape `1 x None`, then you should not include dense layers and use `average` pooling at the end to collapse the response to a `1 x 1 x None` output.

**Edit**: If you have an image of size `276 x n x 3`, where it has variable number of columns and if you want an output of size `1 x n`, then you can do as follows:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution2D(64,row,1,input_shape=(row,None,3)))
model.add(Convolution2D(1,1,1))
print model.output_shape  # this should print `None x 1 x None x 1`
model.add(flatten())
```

Now, I doubt this network will perform very well since it has only one layer of 64 filters. The receptive field is also too large (e.g. 276 - height of the image). You can do two things:

1. Reduce the receptive field, i.e. instead of convolving the entire column of the image at once, you can convolve only 3 pixels of a column at a time.
2. Have multiple convolutional layers.

In the following, I will assume that the image height is 50. Then you can write a network as follows:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Convolution2D(32,3,1,activation='relu',
          init='he_normal',input_shape=(row,None,3)))  # row = 50
model.add(Convolution2D(32,3,1,activation='relu',init='he_normal'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,1), strides=(2,1), name='pool1'))
model.add(Convolution2D(64,3,1,activation='relu',init='he_normal'))
model.add(Convolution2D(64,3,1,activation='relu',init='he_normal'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,1), strides=(2,1), name='pool2'))
model.add(Convolution2D(128,3,1,activation='relu',init='he_normal'))
model.add(Convolution2D(128,3,1,activation='relu',init='he_normal'))
model.add(Convolution2D(128,3,1,activation='relu',init='he_normal'))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2,1), strides=(2,1), name='pool3'))
model.add(Convolution2D(1,1,1), name='squash_channels')
print model.output_shape  # this should print `None x 1 x None x 1`
model.add(flatten(), name='flatten_input')
```

You should verify that all these convolutional and max-pooling layers are reducing the input height from 50 to 1 after the last max-pooling.

**How to handle variable-sized images**

One way is to first determine a common size for your dataset, e.g. 224. Then construct the network for `224 x n` image as shown above (maybe a little deeper). Now let us say you get an image with a different size, say, `p x n'` where `p > 224` and `n' != n`. You can take a center-crop of image of size `224 x n'` and pass it through the image. You have your feature vector.

If you think that majority of the information is not concentrated around the center, then you can take multiple crops, and then average (or max-pool) the multiple feature vector obtained. Using these methods, I think you should be able to handle variable-sized inputs.

**Edit:**

See the CNN that I defined using `3 x 3` convolutions. Assume that the input is of size `50 x n x 3`. Let us say that we pass an input of size `p x q x r` through a convolutional layer which has `f` filters, each of size `3 x 3`, stride 1. The input has no padding. Then the output of convolutional layer will be of size `(p-2) x (q-2) x f` i.e. the output height and width will be the two less than that of input. Our pooling layers are of size `(2,1)` and stride `(2,1)`. They will halve the input in the y-direction (or halve the image height). Keeping this in mind, the following is straightforward to derive (observe the layer names I have given in my CNN, they are referenced below).

CNN input: `None x 50 x n x 3`

Input of `pool1` layer: `None x 46 x n x 32`
Output of `pool1` layer: `None x 23 x n x 32`

Input of `pool2` layer: `None x 19 x n x 64`
Output of `pool2` layer: `None x 9 x n x 64`  *(I think Keras pooling takes floor i.e. floor(19/2) = 9)*

Input of `pool3` layer: `None x 3 x n x 128`
Output of `pool3` layer: `None x 1 x n x 128`

Input of `squash_channels` layer: `None x 1 x n x 128`
Output of `squash_channels` layer: `None x 1 x n x 1`

Input of `flatten_input` layer: `None x 1 x n x 1`
Output of `flatten_input` layer: `None x n`

I think this is what you wanted. I hope its clear now.

Comment: I gave the input shape `276 x none x 3` since the image had different number of columns and that would be the only I could think of , representing the number of columns

Comment: I have never tried giving `None` but I think it should be fine. The main problem will be the `Dense` layer. You cannot give variable size inputs when you have a `Dense` layer. By the way, dense layer IS fully-connected layers (i.e. they are synonyms). So I don't get your first comment.

Comment: Ohh.. I thought  use of the dense layer wasn't clear, which is why i clarified it.

Comment: Ohh... sorry.. I have given you incorrect information.. I will change the post.

Comment: the input data given to the CNN is actually image slices done columnwise, thought the entire image.. so the input shape is (276,3). Also changed in the post above.

Comment: Well..  I guess the way to go is knowing how i should handle variable sized images.

Comment: I guess you right about the title, I am bit unsure on why you are handling it the way you are handling.  your CNN doesn't have a dense layer, and output a 1 datapoint..  

My method is based on  paper: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/CNN_ASLPTrans2-14.pdf

about LWS -  so my way of easily implementing LWS was to seperate the image in to section and keep the same weights in there.  I guess i cannot reduce the receptive field anymore, but using more convolution should be possible.

Comment: 1. I do not know that paper. If the authors suggest some other way, you should go with that, I came up with this in the past 30 minutes. 2. On why I do not have a dense layer: because it cannot handle images with variable columns, which I thought was the crux of your problem. Dense layer is nothing but `w^t*x`, now if `w` is of size `m x n`, then it expects input to have `n` neurons, so that after multiplication, it outputs `m x n * n = m` neurons. Read intro section on the 1st page [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1406.4729.pdf) if you have further doubts.

Comment: Your receptive field is already too large = image height. If you cannot reduce it due to some special structure of your images, then I will not argue. However, if you start with a smaller receptive field and gradually build it up, it is generally better. For example, if you have 1 convolution layer of size `7` versus if you have three convolution layers of size 3, stride 1. The latter is usually better. Read section 2.3- [this](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1409.1556.pdf) paper for more info.So instead of convolving all 50 pixels of image column at once, I split them up over many conv/max-pool layers.

Comment: Hmm.. the paper (microsoft) doesn't explicitly state anything doing convolution in the way i suggest. So doing convolution the way you suggest is possibility.  To be honest I am not sure i am able to see how you are actually reducing the from your input shape to a single feature value.

Comment: Ok. I have given my last shot at explaining how the input reduces to a feature vector whose length is equal to image columns. One mistake that I had done in my earlier answer was to define `(2,2)` maxPool layer. It should have been `(2,1)` maxPool layer with `(2,1)` stride. I have fixed that now.